# 'zef --verbose install Inline::Perl5' , install fails. I get ' t/p5_object_destructor.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 20 Failed: 2)'

Tags: perl, raku, zef

Using Linux Mint 19.1(Ubuntu based distro).
All other `Inline::Perl5` tests pass but install fails because `t/p5_object_destructor.t` fails.
zef install works on another module so problem is specific to this module test.
This is a new Raku installation, only the successful test module added as I  tried to scope  the problem.
I am reluctant to use 'force-test to override failure' without some advice.

Comment: Ask niner, or report a bug at https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/issues ­— it's unlikely that we can help, especially without the actual test output.

Answer (score 4):

The test in question relies on the destruction of objects by the GC to happen at the expected time. Unfortunately, forcing the GC to destroy something when you want it to isn't simple. It's possible that some small change, like a side-effect from an optimization, causes the exact behavior of the GC to change and the test to no longer succeed.

It's probably fine to `--force-test` in this case.

Comment: Thanks timotimo. I will hold off using --force-test for a little while in the hope that someone can identify the underlying issue, but at least you have reduced my concerns about forcing the matter. If worst comes to worst and forcing the matter causes a problem, I could always reinstall perp6 from scratch...